# How can I see the exact command line being executed inside some bash instance?

Tags: bash, process, debugging

I have a long running `bash` instance (inside a `screen` session) that is executing a complex set of commands inside a loop (with each loop doing pipes, redirects, etc).

The long command line was written inside the terminal - it's not inside any script. Now, I know the bash process ID, and I have root access - how can I see the exact command line being executed inside that `bash`?

*Example*

```
bash$ echo $$
1234
bash$ while true ; do \
    someThing | somethingElse 2>/foo/bar | \
    yetAnother ; sleep 600 ; done
```

And in another shell instance, I want to see the command line executed inside PID 1234:

```
bash$ echo $$
5678
bash$ su -
sh# cd /proc/1234
sh# # Do something here that will display the string  \
   'while true ; do someThing | somethingElse 2>/foo/bar | \
    yetAnother ; sleep 600 ; done'
```

Is this possible?

#### EDIT #1

Adding counter-examples for some answers I've got.

1. About using the `cmdline` under `/proc/PID`: that doesn't work, at least not in my scenario. Here's a simple example:

   ```
   $ echo $$
   8909

   $ while true ; do echo 1 ; echo 2>/dev/null ; sleep 30 ; done
   ```

   In another shell:

   ```
   $ cat /proc/8909/cmdline
   bash
   ```
2. Using `ps -p PID --noheaders -o cmd` is just as useless:

   ```
   $ ps -p 8909 --no-headers -o cmd
   bash
   ```
3. `ps -eaf` is also not helpful:

   ```
   $ ps -eaf | grep 8909
   ttsiod    8909  8905  0 10:09 pts/0    00:00:00 bash
   ttsiod   30697  8909  0 10:22 pts/0    00:00:00 sleep 30
   ttsiod   31292 13928  0 10:23 pts/12   00:00:00 grep --color=auto 8909
   ```

   That is, there's no output of the ORIGINAL command line, which is what I'm looking for - i.e the `while true ; do echo 1 ; echo 2>/dev/null ; sleep 30 ; done`.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

I knew I was grasping at straws, but UNIX never fails!

Here's how I managed it:

```
bash$ gdb --pid 8909
...
Loaded symbols for /lib/i386-linux-gnu/i686/cmov/libnss_files.so.2
0xb76e7424 in __kernel_vsyscall ()
```

Then at the `(gdb)` prompt I ran the command, `call write_history("/tmp/foo")` which will write this history to the file `/tmp/foo`.

```
(gdb) call write_history("/tmp/foo")
$1 = 0
```

I then detach from the process.

```
(gdb) detach
Detaching from program: /bin/bash, process 8909
```

And quit `gdb`.

```
(gdb) q
```

And sure enough...

```
bash$ tail -1 /tmp/foo
while true ; do echo 1 ; echo 2>/dev/null ; sleep 30 ; done
```

For easy future re-use, I wrote a [bash script](https://github.com/ttsiodras/utils/blob/master/showBashCmdline.sh), automating the process.

Comment: +1 very nice sleuthing.Be sure to mark this as the excepted A in 2 days.

Comment: @slm: Thanks! I'll write a blog post about it - it was fun, hunting this down.

Comment: With *readline* enabled you can also do this in `gdb`: `print (char *)rl_line_buffer`. The current command in a sequence is  `print (char *)the_printed_command`. You may also `call history_builtin()`, but that will output on the tty of the bash process, so it might be less useful.

Comment: @slm: Couldn't resist - I blogged about it here: http://users.softlab.ece.ntua.gr/~ttsiod/bashheimer.html

Comment: Is bash thread-safe? You'll have to hope you're not modifying some internal state that upsets the currently-executing code when you execute something from gdb. In practice, bash will almost certainly be just waiting for its child process to finish whenever you happen to suspend it with gdb.

Comment: read this post, read your blog, your commandlinefu is epic!

Answer (score 5):

Since the command is still running in screen, its parent bash has not reread any history so:

- reattach to screen
- press `^Z` then `up arrow`
- bonus: wrap the command in single quotes (navigating with `^A^A` - because screen(1) - and `^E`) and echo + redirect into a file
- `fg` to pursue command execution

There are caveats, but this is useful enough, most of the time.

Comment: Yes, even killing it and pressing `up`. Though you have to be confident that it will start again without any problem, but if it doesn't then you'd have the same problem after a reboot anyway. You just have to choose your moment when a downtime wouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 1):

I know you found your own answer, but is there a reason you can't do something like this:

```
(set -x; for f in 1 2 3 4 ; do  echo "$f"; sleep $f; done)
```

Perhaps you can't co-mingle the output of the actual job and the output from bash showing the currently executing line.

Also, FWIW, if you prefer verbosity, `set -o xtrace`.