# How to get whole command line from a process?

Tags: scripting, process, ps, busybox

How can I get the command arguments or the whole command line from a running process using its process name?

For example this process:

```
# ps
PID   USER     TIME   COMMAND
 1452 root       0:00 /sbin/udhcpc -b -T 1 -A 12 -i eth0 -p /var/run/udhcpc.eth0.pid
```

And what I want is `/sbin/udhcpc -b -T 1 -A 12 -i eth0 -p /var/run/udhcpc.eth0.pid` or the arguments. I know the process name and want its arguments. I'm using Busybox on SliTaz.

Comment: Do you want to process the output from `ps` (not recommended) or are you looking for some alternative command to `ps` that will give you the output? What needs to be done when `ps` gives multiple lines of output? print all/first/last?

Comment: Which operating system do you use?

Comment: I edited my question. I know the process name and want its arguments. I'm using SliTaz (minimalistic linux) with Busybox.

Comment: @Michael Have you tried `arg` like `command` as per @John [answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/163146/66803)?

Comment: Yes but how to write it to a variable?
I think of two command:
PID=`pidof <process name>`
ps -o pid,args|grep $PID|tr -s " "|cut -d " " -f 2
But this way I don't get the args in one variable

Comment: @Michael I edited my answer accordingly. You should be more specific about your needs when writing your question ;)

Comment: Sorry, my fault. I don't have -p option using Busybox. Any further advices?

Comment: cat /proc/<PID>/cmdline

Answer (score 146, accepted):

You could use the `-o` switch to specify your output format:

```
$ ps -eo args
```

From [the man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ps):

> Command with all its arguments as a string. Modifications to the arguments may be shown. [...]

You may also use the `-p` switch to select a specific PID:

```
$ ps -p [PID] -o args
```

`pidof` may also be used to switch from process name to PID, hence allowing the use of `-p` with a name:

```
$ ps -p $(pidof dhcpcd) -o args
```

Of course, you may also use `grep` for this (in which case, you must add the `-e` switch):

```
$ ps -eo args | grep dhcpcd | head -n -1
```

GNU ps will also allow you to remove the headers (of course, this is unnecessary when using `grep`):

```
$ ps -p $(pidof dhcpcd) -o args --no-headers
```

On other systems, you may pipe to AWK or sed:

```
$ ps -p $(pidof dhcpcd) -o args | awk 'NR > 1'
$ ps -p $(pidof dhcpcd) -o args | sed 1d
```

Edit: if you want to catch this line into a variable, just use `$(...)` as usual:

```
$ CMDLINE=$(ps -p $(pidof dhcpcd) -o args --no-headers)
```

or, with `grep` :

```
$ CMDLINE=$(ps -eo args | grep dhcpcd | head -n -1)
```

Comment: @Michael replace `args` with `command` (or `cmd`).

Comment: @Pandya Both `cmd` and `command` are aliases to `args`, this is probably unnecessary.

Comment: I don't have a -p option using Busybox:
Usage: ps [-o COL1,COL2=HEADER] [-T]

Comment: You may use `grep` to catch the line you're actually interested in: `ps -eo args | grep dhcpcd | head -n -1`. I edited my answer.

Comment: Oh, this looks good: ps -o args | grep <process name> | head -n 1

Comment: The command line appears to be truncated at 4096 bytes in the middle of an argvalue. According to https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/91561/ps-full-command-is-too-long this is a problem with older kernels.

Answer (score 55):

#### Method #1 - Using ps

You could use `ps -eaf | grep 1234`.

#### Example

```
$ ps -eaf | grep 28865
saml     28865  9661  0 03:06 pts/2    00:00:00 bash -c sleep 10000; while [ 1 ];do echo hi;sleep 10;done
saml     28866 28865  0 03:06 pts/2    00:00:00 sleep 10000
```

**NOTE:** Busybox's `ps` doesn't include the `-eaf` switches as shown above from a typical `ps` that's included with most Linuxes, however Busybox's `ps` shows what looks to be very similar output to the example I provided. You can install Busybox on most Linuxes and run it like so:

```
$ busybox ps
  852 root       0:00 /sbin/auditd -n
  855 root       0:01 /sbin/audispd
  857 root       0:00 /usr/sbin/sedispatch
  866 root       0:00 /usr/sbin/alsactl -s -n 19 -c -E ALSA_CONFIG_PATH=/etc/alsa/alsactl.conf --initfile=/lib/alsa/init/00main rdaemon
  867 root       0:00 /usr/libexec/bluetooth/bluetoothd
  869 root       0:01 {firewalld} /usr/bin/python -Es /usr/sbin/firewalld --nofork --nopid
  871 root       0:32 /usr/libexec/accounts-daemon
  873 rtkit      0:05 /usr/libexec/rtkit-daemon
  875 root       0:00 /usr/sbin/ModemManager
  876 avahi      0:03 avahi-daemon: running [dufresne.local]
  878 root       0:54 /usr/sbin/irqbalance --foreground
  884 root       0:00 /usr/sbin/smartd -n -q never
  886 avahi      0:00 avahi-daemon: chroot helper
  891 chrony     0:01 /usr/sbin/chronyd
  892 root       0:01 /usr/lib/systemd/systemd-logind
  893 dbus       1:28 /bin/dbus-daemon --system --address=systemd: --nofork --nopidfile --systemd-activation
```

#### Method #2 - Using /proc

You can also look at the `cmdline` file that each PID has under `/proc/<pid>`.

```
$ cat /proc/28865/cmdline 
bash-csleep 10000; while [ 1 ];do echo hi;sleep 10;done
```

But notice that it's missing the spacing. This is due to a NUL character being used within this file to separate your command line arguments. Not to worry though, these can be stripped out.

```
$ tr '\0' ' ' </proc/28865/cmdline
bash -c sleep 10000; while [ 1 ];do echo hi;sleep 10;done
```

#### References

- [How can I see the exact command line being executed inside some bash instance?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/159010/how-can-i-see-the-exact-command-line-being-executed-inside-some-bash-instance/159012#159012)

Comment: The `/proc/*/cmdline` method is very useful when `ps` command not available.

Comment: I tried this and did `hexdump -C /proc/123/cmdline` before I read to the end of the post about tr, so I guess that's another way.  I have ps but none of the described arguments worked for me.

Comment: Thanks for including info on the NUL character being used for spaces in the /proc/ output, I was confused how exactly `ps` and these other tools were getting the command line with spaces in the right places.

Answer (score 18):

Try something like this:

(example output from busybox on OpenWrt on one of my routers)

```
root@ap8:~# xargs -0 printf '%s\n' </proc/991/cmdline
/usr/sbin/uhttpd
-f
-h
/www
-r
ap8
-x
/cgi-bin
-u
/ubus
-t
60
-T
30
-k
20
-A
1
-n
3
-N
100
-R
-p
0.0.0.0:80
-p
[::]:80
```

`/proc/$PID/cmdline` contains the arguments of process `$PID` like a C-ish strings one after another. Each string is zero terminated.

Quotes arround some arguments or options are shell stuff. You have to look closer at the lines being shown and where spaces or other characters with special meaning for the shell are used. You will need to quote that character(s) somehow or the complete argument when joining these lines to a command line again.

Comment: `tr "\0" " " </proc/991/cmdline`

Comment: @Cyrus: You cannot distinguish args containg spaces from adjacent separate args then. By replacing the zero byte with a space you destroy information.

Comment: I do agree replacing `\0` with ` ` to be bad, but I think `tr '\0' '\n' < /proc/$foo/cmdline` to be a bit simpler than `xargs`.

Comment: `printf` makes it easier to add quotes to the output, insert a space instead of the new line and so on. When thinking of adding more processing, the way over `printf` is a good start.

Comment: This is the best answer for distributions such as Alpine.

Answer (score 17):

Knowing the PID, just exec

> cat /proc/pid/cmdline

For instance, for PID = 127

```
# cat /proc/127/cmdline ; echo ""
/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-8-oracle-x64//bin/java-Djava.util.logging.config.file=/opt/tomcat/conf/logging.properties-Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager-Djava.library.path=/usr/lib/jni-javaagent:/jmxtrans-agent-1.2.2.jar=/opt/tomcat/conf/jmxtrans-agent.xml-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=5000-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false-Djava.endorsed.dirs=/opt/tomcat/endorsed-classpath/opt/tomcat/bin/bootstrap.jar:/opt/tomcat/bin/tomcat-juli.jar-Dcatalina.base=/opt/tomcat-Dcatalina.home=/opt/tomcat-Djava.io.tmpdir=/opt/tomcat/temporg.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrapstart
#
```

Comment: Thank you! This is the only answer, which displays the whole length of a very large command.

Answer (score 3):

If you like short commands and pgrep is available, I would suggest `pgrep -fl <process_name>`.

`ps -o args` is truncated

Answer (score 1):

`pgrep -a <name>`

In your example :

`pgrep -a udhcpc`

pgrep does not truncate line, but ps does.

For those that insist on using ps, then do that to avoid truncation :

`ps <processID> | tee`

Answer (score 0):

Coming late to the party: extracting the strings from /proc/$pid/cmdline, and displaying them with proper shell quoting.

This requires bash version 4.4+ (but possibly v5.1 for some bug fixes noted in the CHANGES file)

```bsh
mapfile -d '' -t cmd < /proc/$pid/cmdline
echo "${cmd[@]@Q}"
```

- `mapfile` reads the *lines* of a file into an array
- the `-d ''` option  uses null instead of newline as the line terminator
- `@Q` transformation emits each element of the array with shell quoting

Demo:

```bsh
$ sh -c "echo 'hello world'; sleep 5m" &
[1] 14844
hello world
$ pid=$!
$ mapfile -d '' -t cmd < /proc/$pid/cmdline
$ declare -p cmd
declare -a cmd=([0]="sh" [1]="-c" [2]="echo 'hello world'; sleep 5m")
$ echo "${cmd[@]@Q}"
'sh' '-c' 'echo '\''hello world'\''; sleep 5m'
```